# Publish and Deploy .NET Core SignalR on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a working .NET Core SignalR project locally.
I published the project to a local folder.
I then copied the files to an IIS server.

I get a HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized Error when browsing the service.
I checked the ACL of the folder which contains the library and have given
full access to IIS_USR

The web.config file is somewhat empty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you implement Authentication feature in your project? Check the application in IIS whether you enable any authentication.

Comment: I don't authenticate the hub at the moment.  I am deploying to a DEV server.

Comment: Does it mistake to write `IIS_USR`? Do you add `IUSR`? Try to follow Click on Authentication and click edit after choosing Anonymous Authentication. In the opening window select Application Pool identity and click OK. "

Comment: Your asp.net core app should have appsettings.json not web.config